# URL flow when writing a wizard in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, validation, wizard

I am writing a basic wizard for my web site.  It will have 4 steps, and each needs to have its own URL.  Each step must first validate a form before moving on.

If the form for a given step fails to validate, I don't want the URL to change.  But if it passes, I do want it to move on.

What is the preferred way to write this?  Using javascript alone to validate is not secure enough.  I have 2 ideas so far but I don't love either:

1) Post the form to the same script and use a header() redirect to the next step if it passes.
2) Send an ajax post to validate and then use location.href to send user to the next step if it passes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks, Brian

Comment: Why do you "not love either"? Both of these approaches sound perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to avoid using javascript.  So that leaves the first option, which is fully do-able, I'd just need to be completely sure to avoid any output being sent prior to the validation (but that shouldn't be a problem).  Also it just struck me as weird that either solution requires two separate requests to the server.

Comment: @Brian - well, you could have each step POST to the next step and have the next step process the data from the previous one if you wanted to avoid multiple server requests.  I don't think I would recommend that though (just for encapsulation purposes)

Comment: @Eric - I agree, I've also considered using one centralized 'wizard' controller.  The issue is that I have to maintain separate URLs for each step, which seems to be putting me in conflict with proper design.

Comment: The "Two requests to the server" thing is silly to worry about.  POST/Redirect/GET is a common practice, arguably a best-practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer option #1, since it doesn't require javascript.

However, you'll also want to consider what happens when somebody bookmarks or skips directly to the wrong step.

Comment: Good caveat.  Each step should inspect and validate session data from the previous steps, and take corrective action if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your option #1 is exactly the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you can combine these two approaches so that:

1. If the user has JS enabled, they get a smoother experience (no page reload)
2. If they don't, no functionality is lost

You would do that using a standard trick:

```
<form name="foo" action="bar.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="ajax_handler(); return false;" />
</form>
```

This will require some competent engineering so that `ajax_handler()` can utilize the same code as `bar.php` does to process the form data. Also, you should pay special attention in the AJAX path so that things like the back button continue to work as the user expects.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to have all the validation logic (between this steps) in one single PHP page (which then always gets `POST`ed to).

At postback, do the validation for the current step and (only if valid) branch out to the next step. You also need to persist the 'previous' validations between posts.

You can still have `different` URL's in the sense of `myform.php?step=1` and `myform.php?step=2` and ... With some simple url rewriting that could be `myform/step1`, `myform/step2`, ...